# Targeting nested nodegroups fails with "Minion did not return. [No response]", despite the hosts responding if targeted via other criteria

Tags: python, salt-stack

I'm having an odd issue with nested nodegroups in that I can't seem to target them.  Here's my nodegroups section of my master config file:

---

**/etc/salt/master:**

```
nodegroups:
  linuxlabs: 'E@^pubbox'
  linuxtest: 'N@linuxlabs'
```

---

Now here's an example of the target failing on the nested nodegroup, despite being able to target the parent nodegroup and the hosts individually.

```
[root@salt-master ~]# salt 'pubbox10.example.com' test.ping
pubbox10.example.com:
    True

[root@salt-master ~]# salt 'pubbox44.example.com' test.ping
pubbox44.example.com:
    True

[root@salt-master ~]# salt -N linuxtest test.ping
pubbox10.example.com:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
pubbox44.example.com:
    Minion did not return. [No response]

[root@salt-master ~]# salt -N linuxlabs test.ping
pubbox44.example.com:
    True
pubbox10.example.com:
    True
```

---

Adding "**-l debug**" or "**-l trace**" doesn't really reveal much.  In the -l debug output, actually, it shows that the nested nodegroups are being resolved to their correct hostnames.  In the "-l trace" output, the terminal is just spammed relentlessly with the same message:

```
[root@salt-master ~]# salt -N linuxtest test.ping -l trace
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
...
[DEBUG   ] nodegroup_comp(linuxlabs) => ['(', 'E@^pubbox', ')']
[DEBUG   ] nodegroup_comp(linuxtest) => ['(', '(', 'E@^pubbox', ')', ')']
...
[TRACE   ] get_event() received = {'tag': 'salt/job/20160609132845009910/new', 'data': {'tgt_type': 'compound', 'jid': '20160
609132845009910', 'tgt': ['(', '(', 'E@^pubbox', ')', ')'], '_stamp': '2016-06-09T17:28:45.011228', 'user': 'root', 'arg': []
, 'fun': 'test.ping', 'minions': ['pubbox10.example.com', 'pubbox44.example.com']}}
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
...
```

^^ this message is repeated 2000+ times, finally ending a few seconds later in:

```
...
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[TRACE   ] _get_event() waited 0 seconds and received nothing
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded no_return.output
[TRACE   ] data = {'pubbox10.example.com': 'Minion did not return. [No response]'}
pubbox10.example.com:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded no_return.output
[TRACE   ] data = {'pubbox44.example.com': 'Minion did not return. [No response]'}
pubbox44.example.com:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
```

---

I tried a few variations on the nested nodegroup.  For example, instead of making the parent contain an "E@" prefix, I changed it to "L@" and explicitly listed out the hostnames.  Same result.

---

Here's my **salt --versions-report**:

```
[root@salt-master ~]# salt --versions-report
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2015.8.10

Dependency Versions:
         Jinja2: 2.8
       M2Crypto: 0.24.0
           Mako: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
         Python: 2.7.11 (default, Mar 24 2016, 22:19:35)
           RAET: 0.6.5
        Tornado: 4.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.4
           cffi: 1.5.2
       cherrypy: 3.2.3
       dateutil: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: 1.5.1
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: 1.4.4
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.7
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: 2.14
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         pygit2: Not Installed
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed

System Versions:
           dist:   
        machine: i86pc
        release: 5.11
```

---

Have I stumbled upon a bug?  Or have I misconfigured my nodegroups?  For what it's worth, I checked the release notes between this release and the current version of Salt, and didn't find anything about resolving nested nodegroup issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug. Would you mind opening an issue on SaltStack's github issue tracker?
http://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/new

Thanks!